# while create Tuple object in c# gives error?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to create tuple object with int,Dictionary(int,object).

```
Tuple<int, Dictionary<int,object>> OLECache= new Tuple<int, Dictionary<int, object>>();
```

whats wrong with this..can anyone explain ?why this show error?

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: `(int, Dictionary<int,object>) OLECache = ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because the Tuple constructor must have all the expected item values

```
Tuple<int, Dictionary<int,object>> OLECache= new Tuple<int, Dictionary<int, object>>(1, new Dictionary<int, object>());
```

or you can simplify to

```
(int, Dictionary<int,object>) OLECache= (1, new Dictionary<int, object>());
```